# vim-ipython under OSX

Tags: macos, vim-ipython

I've tried to install vim-ipython on my OSX system.
After entering ":IPython" i get:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config.py:13: ShimWarning: The I Python.config package has been deprecated. You should import from traitlets.con
fig instead.
"You should import from traitlets.config instead.", ShimWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/init.py:13: ShimWarnin
g: The IPython.kernel package has been deprecated. You should import from ipyk
ernel or jupyter_client instead.
"You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/Users/amitm02/vim_ipython.py", line 145, in km_from_string
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 
193, in find_connection_file
return sorted(matches, key=lambda f: os.stat(f).st_atime)[-1]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 
193, in 
return sorted(matches, key=lambda f: os.stat(f).st_atime)[-1]
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './cv.py'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to install it? brew? source? pip install?

Comment: @AeroBuffalo I've used the quick start guide in: https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython